# Do WebSockets trigger IOException: Too many opened files?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, websocket, spring-websocket

I have spring-boot (version: 2.2.1.Release) application. The application has a scheduled task (call it **Task-A**) that makes a lot of requests to third api, that occasionally may be down. Also the application has an opened WebSocket, so that client may check in real-time status of some process. Web socket has following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebSocket
class WebSocketConfig : WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {


    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {

        registry.addEndpoint("/ws/activity")
                .setAllowedOrigins("origin-from-where-connection-to-socket-comes.com")
                .withSockJS()
    }
}
```

And there is the second scheduled task (call it **Task-B**) that writes information for clients into the socket every 5 seconds:

```
@Component
class ChargersScheduled
@Autowired constructor(
        private val processMonitor: ProcessMonitor,
        private val messagingTemplate: SimpMessagingTemplate
) {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    fun getSchedulersActivity () {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/web-socket/activity", processMonitor.checkActivity())
    }

}
```

At some point of time **Task-A** starts to emit `IOException : Too many open files`, a minute or two later logs are starting to fill with:

```
o.a.t.u.n.Acceptor                       : Socket accept failed
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:461)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:73)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:95)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is that caused by clients attempting to connect to WebSockets or making simple requests to the server or, perhaps, both? Aside from increasing `ulimit` (already done) what is the way of mitigating the problem? As for now I had to restart the application since it hanged, as if it was under DDOS attack.

Comment: Yes, if you never close them, or are leaking FDs somewhere else.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne could you please elaborate? I am writing data into the socket every 5 seconds; users might connect any time to get the data. When should I cause close the socket?

Comment: When the peer disconnects, or when you get any `IOException` or `SocketException` other than a read timeout: and you might want to close on those as well.

Comment: You should use the embedded keep alive: it is safer

Answer (score -1):

you should increase the File Descriptor size. Ulimit itself is not enough. You should apply some changes on some other files.
see this [link](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-03-26-increase-open-files-limit)

Comment: He should fix his FD leaks.

Comment: Yes but I guess you haven't checked the link I attached and gave me - 1